# Redirect users on quick action in lightning

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, lightning-experience

Is there any way to call the client-side JS controller on load of lightning component, something like `<ui:onload action={!c.redirect}`

The use case is I need to redirect users on click of quick action button.

Answer (score 3):

I did something like this

```
    <aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.navigate}"/>
```